# Arch Linux grub installation error "airootfs"

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, boot-loader

I was following the official installation tutorial. Everything was smooth until the boot loader section.

I had encountered the error of

```
/usr/bin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'airootfs'.
```

same as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245857/155686) while executing the command:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I was installing arch on VirtualBox and was following the official's wiki tutorial [GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) section step by step.

I can boot into grub successfully but all that I can see is only a grub shell.
As a inference, I think it has derailed since the step to generate the grub configuration file. 
Hope that my info is helpful.

---

BTW in fact, I had also encountered this error in the previous step - installing the grub

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

I added the root directory parameter and it went on without appearing error.

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

I did so because I mounted my main Linux partition /dev/sda3 on /mnt
but there isn't any root or boot directory parameter for me to use in grub-mkconfig.

Here is my partition table displayed by fdisk utility:
[image: mypartitiontable]

Thx a lot.
Regards.

Comment: what error? which error?

Comment: @user137124 just a mistake. Sorry for my unclear title. Still, I improved it and hope for someone to reply.

Comment: Still unclear, please post the exact error message.

Comment: @JohnsonSteward I'm sorry, you must have been tired of those unclear questions. I again tried my best to describe the question. Please reply if you still don't understand the error I stated, then I'll post the full screen shot on here. Great thanks.

Comment: @李智修 seems like you should do `grub2-mkconfig` **in** the chroot instead of doing it outside. `grub2-mkconfig` uses `grub-probe` to detect real devices associated with mount points, while `airootfs` (archiso's rootfs) is loaded into the ram and don't have a canonical path.

Comment: The correct way to install and make config for grub is doing it inside the chroot. Otherwise you may be greeted with strange filesystems which only exist in livecd (e.g. `rootfs`, `/cow` and many more)

Comment: @JohnsonSteward I see, thanks for your reply. I think official's wiki should have added this notice(since a small frustration may easily defeat a Arch newbie)

Comment: OK, when the question's reopened, add the answer yourself!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Seems like you should do `grub2-mkconfig` **in** the chroot instead of doing it outside. `grub2-mkconfig` uses `grub-probe` to detect real devices associated with mount points, while `airootfs` (archiso's `rootfs`) is loaded into the ram and doesn't have a canonical path.

So before installing grub and generating config, do this first:

```
arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Comment: I get the same errors as OP. The commands listed above result in *"Error failed to setup chroot..."*. I wouldn't be in this fine mess if Arch did not break itself after the last update. Its amazing how often this OS breaks itself. Its worse than damn Microsoft Windows.

Comment: But I am currently fine with the use of AUR from time to time without breaking my setup. Maybe limiting the use of self-build(build from source by yourself) may help? I always enter Y when pacman ask me anything lol

Comment: But the GRUB install commands aren't available inside the chroot...

Comment: @flarn2006 You need to install the grub package inside the chroot.

Comment: @flarn2006 `pacman -S grub`

Comment: This is the right answer, thanks! similarly: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1225067#p1225067