# Grub installation error while installing arch

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub

I tried `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/b`

I got output...

> failed to get canonical path of /b

I don't know why this is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a directory `/b`?

Comment: @roaima sorry I didn't answer my question. I had already fixed the problem but, I can't use SE properly in mobile that's why I didn't answer. I was thinking to answer all of my question which I created currently I am facing the issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645797/grub-rescue-error-insmod-normal. I request to check it... I am answering those questions which I solved

Comment: @roaima I have added lot more information in that question please check it now...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/b` doesn't have access to run as a normal user. This only can be run as root user(arch-chroot). Here's the answer which helped me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261409/467213. And, not every user can run the code `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/b`. I tried to run the code as a root user I got another issue. Here's the question which helped me https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252598. I am unable to copy the answer(cause, I am using SE from mobile. I will edit my answer later.