# Grub rescue error (insmod normal)

Tags: grub, error-handling, rescue

[image]

I was trying to make it normal from grub rescue error. But, msdos7 is returning that filesystem is ext2. When I write insmod normal I get "invalid file name 'hd0,msdos7/i386-pc/normal.mod"

How can I fix it? I have bootable USB . that's arch Linux. Even, I tried by bootable USB also. When I reboot my laptop that(grub Loader) don't show anymore(like it had erased automatically when rebooting). I was following the answer
https://askubuntu.com/a/462995

When I tried to search `search.file ...` I got an error unknown command 'search.file'.

[image]

```
root@mint:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1912557568 bytes, 3735464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 298.9 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HTS72323
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcdead0a2

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      1026048 272532369 271506322 129.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       272533504 273694719   1161216   567M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3       273696768 274747391   1050624   513M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda4       274747392 625142447 350395056 167.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       274749440 275726335    976896   477M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda6       275728384 277682175   1953792   954M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       277684224 625142447 347458224 165.7G 83 Linux
```

This is how I installed grubloader but, I am getting the grub error although. /dev/sda7 is arch Linux. And, /dev/sda1 is windows.

I had Kali earlier. I had deleted partition/volume of kali,swap and grub from windows manager.

[image]

I noticed that type /dev/sda7 is `ext2`. But, I remember that I formatted it to `ext4`.

Now, I have Linux Mint bootable USB.

```
root@mint:~# mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: /mnt: /dev/sda5 already mounted on /mnt.
root@mint:~# grub-install /dev/sda5
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
```

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

I was following [the video](https://youtu.be/biGNIMIRgNU?t=303). I notice that he set flags to bios_grub. But, I don't have bios_grub. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

By following [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=8lod8sRb_6I) I had solved this issue.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt
reboot now
```

But, I am facing [another issue here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645894/grub-error-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported)